Is std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(value)) useful?
Following code shows how to store type information in compilation time, using template.
My question is, in the Any::Any(T&& value), is std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(value)) useful? Because std::decay_t will remove reference type. Or we can use std::decay_t<T>(value) directly?
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <span>
#include <functional>

struct Person
{
    std::string_view name;
    std::size_t age;

    void say(std::string_view msg) { std::cout << name << " say: " << msg << std::endl; }
};

class Any;

struct Type
{
    using Destroy = void (*)(void*);
    using Construct = void* (*)(void*);
    using Method = Any(*)(void*, std::span<Any>);
    using Field = std::pair<Type*, std::size_t>;

    std::string_view name;
    Destroy destroy;
    Construct copy;
    Construct move;
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view, Field> fields;
    std::unordered_map<std::string_view, Method> methods;
};

class Any
{
    Type* type;
    void* data;
    uint8_t flag;

public:
    Any() : type(nullptr), data(nullptr), flag(0) {}
    Any(Type* type, void* data) : type(type), data(data), flag(0B00000001) {}
    Any(const Any& other);
    Any(Any&& other);
    template <typename T>
    Any(T&& value); // packing
    ~Any();

    template <typename T>
    T& cast(); // unpacking

    Type* GetType() const { return type; }

    Any invoke(std::string_view name, std::span<Any> args);

    void foreach(const std::function<void(std::string_view, Any)>& fn);
};

Any::Any(const Any& other)
{
    type = other.type;
    data = type->copy(other.data);
    flag = 0;
}

Any::Any(Any&& other)
{
    type = other.type;
    data = type->move(other.data);
    flag = 0;
}

template <typename T>
Any::Any(T&& value)
{
    type = type_of<std::decay_t<T>>();
    data = new std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(value));
    flag = 0;
}

Any::~Any()
{
    if (!(flag & 0B00000001))
    {
        if (data && type)
        {
            type->destroy(data);
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& Any::cast()
{
    if (type != type_of<T>())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "type mismatch" };
    }
    return *static_cast<T*>(data);
}

void Any::foreach(const std::function<void(std::string_view, Any)>& fn)
{
    for (auto& [name, field] : type->fields)
    {
        fn(name, Any(field.first, static_cast<char*>(data) + field.second));
    }
}

Any Any::invoke(std::string_view name, std::span<Any> args)
{
    auto it = type->methods.find(name);
    if (it == type->methods.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "method not found" };
    }
    return it->second(data, args);
}

template <typename T>
struct member_fn_traits;

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct member_fn_traits<R(C::*)(Args...)>
{
    using return_type = R;
    using class_type = C;
    using args_type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <auto ptr>
auto* type_ensure()
{
    using traits = member_fn_traits<decltype(ptr)>;
    using class_type = typename traits::class_type;
    using result_type = typename traits::return_type;
    using args_type = typename traits::args_type;

    return +[](void* object, std::span<Any> args) -> Any
        {
            auto self = static_cast<class_type*>(object);
            return[=]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
            {
                if constexpr (std::is_void_v<result_type>)
                {
                    (self->*ptr)(args[Is].cast<std::tuple_element_t<Is, args_type>>()...);
                    return Any{};
                }
                else
                {
                    auto result = (self->*ptr)(args[Is].cast<std::tuple_element_t<Is, args_type>>()...);
                    return Any{ result };
                }
            }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<args_type>>{});
        };
}

template <typename T>
Type* type_of()
{
    static Type type;
    type.name = typeid(T).name();
    type.destroy = [](void* obj) { delete static_cast<T*>(obj); };
    type.copy = [](void* obj) { return (void*)(new T(*static_cast<T*>(obj))); };
    type.move = [](void* obj) { return (void*)(new T(std::move(*static_cast<T*>(obj)))); };
    return &type;
}

template <>
Type* type_of<Person>()
{
    static Type type;
    type.name = "Person";
    type.destroy = [](void* obj) { delete static_cast<Person*>(obj); };
    type.copy = [](void* obj) { return (void*)(new Person(*static_cast<Person*>(obj))); };
    type.move = [](void* obj) { return (void*)(new Person(std::move(*static_cast<Person*>(obj)))); };
    type.fields.insert({ "name", {type_of<std::string_view>(), offsetof(Person, name)} });
    type.fields.insert({ "age", {type_of<std::size_t>(), offsetof(Person, age)} });
    type.methods.insert({ "say", type_ensure<&Person::say>() });
    return &type;
};

int main()
{
    Any person = Person{ "Tom", 18 };
    std::vector<Any> args = { std::string_view{"Hello"} };
    person.invoke("say", args);
    // => Tom say: Hello

    auto f = [](std::string_view name, Any value)
        {
            if (value.GetType() == type_of<std::string_view>())
            {
                std::cout << name << " = " << value.cast<std::string_view>() << std::endl;
            }
            else if (value.GetType() == type_of<std::size_t>())
            {
                std::cout << name << " = " << value.cast<std::size_t>() << std::endl;
            }
        };

    person.foreach(f);
    // => 
    // name = Tom
    // age = 18
    return 0;
}

I have tried std::decay_t<T>(value) and it works, I just wonder whether the complex format has special considering.

The shown code has very little to do with your question, you're just asking what std::forward means.

I know the forward will keep the reference type: left reference or right reference, but I wonder the meaning of the combination of decay and forward.

There's nothing special, how the return value of std::forward is used doesn't impact what std::forward means. Do you understand what std::decay means?

I know std::decay is used to trim the reference, constant, change array to pointer. So I want to know is, comparing with std::decay_t<T>(value), the std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(value)) seems like useless? Because no matter what the reference is, std::decay_t only return raw type.

"seems like useless?" no, it's not useless, one moves and the other doesn't. I think you don't fully understand what std::forward is supposed to do, perhaps because you don't understand what move semantics are. You should read the links above and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move.

Maybe I finally know what happens. in new std::decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(value));, std::decay_t<T> has finished the work of get raw type, (std::forward<T>(value)) is to call the constructor, and std::forward<T>(value) is to make sure calling ctor(T&&) or ctor(T&) base on input parameter reference type?

Yes. As a side note, you should use standard nomenclature and not invent your own names. It's "lvalue reference" not "left reference"and "decayed type" not "raw type". ctor(T&&) is also less clear than T(T&&).

get it, thank you for your patience!
